# Basic question about the Sobolev space $H^1_0(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded and connected Lipschitz domain, and $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ be any function. If I denote for each real $k\in\mathbb{R}$

$$\Omega_k=\{x\in\Omega\ |\ u(x)>k\}$$

how can I rigurously prove that $(u-k)^+:=\max\{u-k,0\}\in H^1_0(\Omega_k)$ for any $k$ with $|\Omega\setminus\Omega_k|>0$ (Lebesgue measure)?

I know that $(u-k)^+\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $(u-k)^+\in H^1(\Omega_k)$ as a consequence, but I don't know how to prove the above fact...

Comment: I modified the statement. Thanks for the example.

Comment: $\Omega_k$ is only defined up to sets of measure 0. Are you picking a particular representative of $u$ to define this set?

Comment: Yes, we can make that if needed.

Comment: What about take $u\in C_c^\infty$, $0\leq u\leq 1$, $u\equiv 1$ on the unit ball $B$, and $u\equiv 0$ outside of $2B$. Set $\Omega:= 2B\cap \{ x_1>0\}$ be a half-ball. Then $|\Omega\setminus\Omega_k|>0$ for every $k<1$, but $(u-k)^+\equiv 1-k$ in a neighborhood of the origin, so it can't be in $H_0^1(\Omega_k)$

Comment: I think (haven't checked carefully) to make this true you need to either assume $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ or to make sure $\Omega_k$ stays far away from $\partial\Omega$.